# JavaScript error when reading a property within the same object?

Tags: javascript

Below is part of a larger JavaScript object in my project.  I have remove a couple thousand lines of code to reveal just the part in question...

**Line 6** below is the line of code in question.

**Simple example of JavaScript**

```
projectTaskModal = {

    // Cache Properties
    cache: {
        $taskDueDateSpan: $('#task-modal-due-date-span'),
        $taskDueDateVal: projectTaskModal.cache.$taskDueDateSpan.dataAttr('due-date'),
    }

}
```

---

**First on that line I had tried this:**
`$taskDueDateVal: projectTaskModal.cache.$taskDueDateSpan.dataAttr('due-date'),`

but this resulted in this console error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined`

**Next I also tried this:**
`$taskDueDateVal: this.$taskDueDateSpan.dataAttr('due-date'),`

but that also resulted in this console error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$taskDueDateSpan' of undefined`

---

As you can see on line 6 I am trying to access the value of line 5.
`projectTaskModal.cache.$taskDueDateSpan`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot refer to an "under construction" object from inside the object literal itself. The only thing to do us update the object after it's initially built.

```
projectTaskModal = {

    // Cache Properties
    cache: {
        $taskDueDateSpan: $('#task-modal-due-date-span')
    }

};

projectTaskModal.cache.$taskDueDateVal = projectTaskModal.cache.$taskDueDateSpan.dataAttr('due-date');
```

Alternatively, initialize *another* variable with that jQuery expression, and use it for both properties:

```
var $dueDateSpan = $('#task-modal-due-date-span');

projectTaskModal = {

    // Cache Properties
    cache: {
        $taskDueDateSpan: $dueDateSpan,
        $taskDueDateVal: $dueDateSpan.dataAttr('due-date')
    }

}
```

Comment: That makes sense and something I wasn't aware of thank you for clarifying!  I'm a bit surprised this is the first time I ran into this issue since I didn't know of it!

Comment: you might want to remove the `$taskDueDateVal` property from the initial construction of `cache` in your first example

Comment: @sfletche yes sorry - I was just doing that; my keyboard was acting really weird and I was getting pretty confused :)

Comment: @sfletche do you mean to not even have an empty value for  `$taskDueDateVal = '',` in my cache object?  In other parts of my app I constantly update the value for it so as @Pointy described would be no issue since I already update it in other sections but I am curious about your comment of removing it altogether from the cache section.  This would mean basically adding this properties `key and value` at a later date instead of just adding it's `value` later.  If that is the case, then I guess I didn't realize that could be done as well!  I'm still learning JS so love the feedback thanks all

Comment: @JasonDavis he means removing the erroneous initialization I copied from your code. It's OK to initialize it to `null` or something, but not really necessary. You can add properties to any object any time you want.

Comment: Yes, you can leave the key out of the object construction altogether and then add it later (as @Pointy is demonstrating here).  Alternatively, in some cases it may be useful (for code-reading purposes) to include the key in the initial construction, but it would probably be best to assign it the value `undefined` (to more clearly denote that the value has not yet been assigned) rather than an empty string (cases may vary).

Comment: @sfletche Also if I understood you correctly, which I think I did,  I would also say that even if I didn't set an actual `value` to my `$taskDueDateVal` property in the cache object, I sort of like having it defined there even if just for the sole purpose of readability so that I know it exist as a property that I will be caching or w/e...if that makes sense.  Not sure if that is a bad idea or not

Comment: @sfletche the comment you posted at the same time above covers my question well, thank you!  Also the tip of assigning it `undefined` is nice!  love it thanks

Answer (score 1):

JS is a language with strict not lazy evaluation.

Which means expressions in a statement are evaluated inside out.

```
projectTaskModal = {

    // Cache Properties
    cache: {
        $taskDueDateSpan: $('#task-modal-due-date-span'),
        $taskDueDateVal: projectTaskModal.cache.$taskDueDateSpan.dataAttr('due-date'),
    }

}
```

So in this statement the right part (the object literal) is evaluated first, then a reference to it is assigned to the variable `projectTaskModal`.

Which means that during its evaluation the value of `projectTaskModal` is `undefined`.